# PHP Form File Upload doesnt work

Tags: php

I want to upload Images or MP4 Videos.

I have this Code:

```
<form role="form" action="addad.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Image or MP4 Please</label>
    <input type="file" id="FileInput" name="file" required>
    <div id="responses"></div>
  </div>
</form>

if(!isset($_FILES['file'])){ 
   echo "No File";
   exit;
}

$uploaddir = '/var/www/xxxxxx.com/control/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
echo $uploadfile;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
   echo "Image succesfully uploaded.";
} else {
   echo "Image uploading failed.";
   exit;
}
```

But its already crashed in isset with Message "No File", when i try to upload...

Any Ideas? 
Already checked PHP User and changed folders to www-data
Also tried permissions 777 but nothing works.

Everytime it looks like, he dont get any file informations or dont see the file. All other fields in my form works. If i dont make exit; it write all other fields to database.

Comment: `$_FILES['file']` will be empty unless you submit the form. Did you submit the form?

Comment: This looks like a great example of why it's better to separate the form presentation from the form processing.  I'll never understand the insistence that these things should be the same page...

Comment: Its different files. PHP File with the Form in Bootstrap and a PHP File to Insert the Informations. But the 2nd File where i will check the $_FILES is empty in $_FILES['file']. And lol.... yes i submit the form

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "submit" input/button is inside the form

```
<form role="form" action="addad.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Image or MP4 Please</label>
    <input type="file" id="FileInput" name="file" required>
    <div id="responses"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit File"/>
</form>
```

In the "addad.php" file, `var_dump($_FILES)` before the "if(!isset())" part and check if your data is beeing shown, something like this:

[image: $_FILES]

Comment: var_dump says: array(0) { }.... and yes my submit button is in form. Also as i said, other fields working... its only the upload but i dont know why :( ////EDIT: Ok found it... but i dont know how to fix it... i want to make this with ajax: <script type="text/javascript">
$("#submitad").click( function() {
  $.post( $("#addad").attr("action"),
    $("#addad :input").serializeArray(),
    function(info){ $(".ajax-content").html(info);
  });
});

$("#addad").submit( function() {
  return false;
});
</script>

Answer (score -1):

Your Condition is Wrong . Use:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
```

Comment: Why is that wrong? I want to look, if isset is NOT (No file). That what you show is, if this exists, than its returned yes.

Comment: Oh Yeah! Actually I havent noticed the form's action page. If you load on same page then your condition will wrong.